# c++ allocate memory array of struc

Tags: c++

I have a macro which is reading a txt file with 348804849 line. I created a structure to storage the information contained in each column of the file and a few more variables that I added. The problem I have is that the memory of my computer is not enough to storage all that information. So, I was trying to allocate memory but I got and error when running my code. These are the related parts of the code. I've simplified names

In the .C

```
ifstream myfile ("file.txt");
    char str[LINE_BUFFER];

if (myfile.is_open()){

    cout << "Theoretical file has been opened succesfully" << endl;

    while (myfile && myfile.getline(str, LINE_BUFFER)){

        myfile >> info[i].thing1 >> info[i].thing2;     
        i++;

        }

    lines_number = i-1;
        myfile.close();

}else cout << "Unable to open file";

info = malloc(lines_number * sizeof *info);
```

and in the .h

```
struct info_t{  
    double thing1;
    double thing2;
};

info_t *info;
```

Error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  >>> Interpreter compilation error:
Unable to allocate section memory!

Comment: You can't have `ifstream` in a *.c* file, nor `cout`. Also using `malloc()` in [tag:c++] is not always a good idea, remember that classes have constructors and that requires the operator `new`. And since this is [tag:c++] use `std::vector` and avoid `malloc()` or `new`.

Comment: Also if you have a new (or badly a malloc) you HAVE TO have a delete (or free for malloc)

Comment: Do you really need to read the entire file in memory, at once? You may want to read - for example - 1000 lines each time, process them and go for the next 1000, until the end.

Comment: Note, just two `double`'s: 348804849×16 ~ 5.2 Gb. Yes, in the heap, but it is restricted with the size of your free RAM.

Comment: Also, you allocate memory after using info table

Comment: @John_West: RAM has absolutely **nothing** to do with heap memory. You don't seem to understand the concept of *virtual memory*.

Comment: What is our error at runtime (if I guess well is "segmentation fault", but...)

Comment: @John_West: You've never heard of paging?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I forgot about secondary storage. But both heap and stack memory is allocated physically somewhere.

Comment: @John_West: That's irrelevant. What is relevant is, that allocated memory consumes address space. Particularly with 32-bit OS's, this is the real limit. Available RAM is merely a performance optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're reading into the array, *then* creating/allocating it. That's backwards.

You'd be better off parsing each line as you read it, ideally. Rather than storing all five gigabytes.